# Need usb write protection

Tags: security

I need to stop a user transfer files to usb from Ubuntu desktop. However, this user should be able to read usb content.

In Windows, we can achieve this through group policy. I tried but completely blocked usb. Is there any option in ubuntu desktop ? kindly help me out please.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. It's also not clear what problem you are encountering. It's not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question with specific context and details so that we have enough information to attempt to answer your question.

Comment: You can add restrictions so that the user can only transfer to their home directory, but not anywhere else